# Unexpected type 'type' error

Tags: python, pyqgis

I have this function:

```
def my_function(self):
    layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
    indexz = self.dlg.comboBox.currentIndex()
    layer=layers[indexz]

    Field_list = []
    self.dlg.comboBox_2.clear()
    for field in layer.pendingFields():
        Field_list.append(field.name())
    self.dlg.comboBox_2.addItems(Field_list)
```

When I run it I get this error:

```
TypeError: QComboBox.addItems(QStringList): argument 1 has unexpected type 'type'
```

Can somone explain what it means?